# Raw folder url path?

Tags: android

How can I get the URL of the raw folder? I do not want to access my asset via id but by path instead.

Comment: What are you looking to do? Can't you just use R.raw.your_object?

Comment: Nope, that doesnt find it. I need the path to check it is there on build.

Comment: Can you use the path provided when you right click->properties?
It should be "yourProject/res/raw"

Comment: if the raw file contains the image and want to set it to ImageView img then the following code is used

img.setBackgroundResource(R.raw.filename);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to give path of raw folder in file(string) path format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924875/how-to-give-path-of-raw-folder-in-filestring-path-format)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

```
Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.cpt.sample/raw/filename");
```

Using this you can access the file in raw folder, if you want to access the file in asset folder use this URL...

```
file:///android_asset/filename
```

Make sure you **don't** add the extension to the filename. E.g. "/movie" **not** "/movie.mp4".

Comment: Make sure you **don't** add the extension to the filename. E.g. "/movie" **not** "/movie.mp4".

Comment: @Karthi: thank you for the answer, can you provide a link to the documentation describing this access pattern?

Comment: In the case of GIF resource, What worked for me is ```file:///android_res/raw/wheel.gif```

Answer (score 14):

This is to find a file named `video.mp4` inside raw folder:

```
    String path = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.video;
```

Comment: R.raw.video will return the id number not the name of the file. This doesn't work.

Comment: I used it like this to load a video and it works. `videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));`

Answer (score 10):

Now u can do this:

```
getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filename)
```

Answer (score 5):

The point with using raw is to access with the id, for example  **R.raw.your_object_id**. If you want to access to your resources with file path then you need to use **assets**.

Then you can use assets like this:

```
InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open("MyFolder/" + "MyFile.db3");
InputStream myInpu1t = myContext.getAssets().open("MyFile_in_the_root.db3");
```

Comment: Thanks, I do this but get an error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: This file can not be opened as a file descriptor; it is probably compressed

Comment: Im trying to load an mp3 so there is no reason why it should be compressed by the packaging

Comment: I do not see reason why you want the path of values/raw folder when you can access this with an id.

Comment: Because im making a native air extension which cannot access the raw folder

Answer (score 1):

***A Generic 100% Working Solution***

Step 1. Create an **Extensions.kt** file

Step 2. Add the below function in *Extensions.kt*

fun Activity.getRawFolderPath(video: Int) = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName().toString() + "/" + video)

*and call it from Activity like:*
**getRawFolderPath(R.raw.video)**

*or from Fragment Like:*
**requireActivity().getRawFolderPath(R.raw.video)**