# Parsing XML file in raw folder using XMLConfiguration

Tags: android, xml-parsing, apache-commons

I'm trying to use XMLConfigurable apache common XML parser to parse an XML file that I appended to the raw folder in android, but i cant find a way to actually get the xml path.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966085/raw-folder-url-path) but it wont work, XMLConfiguration throws error of file not found.
Is there a way to actually get the full path?

I have also tried to use this:

```
context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.kmlsample);
```

But also can't figure out a way to use XMLConfiguration to take InputStream, all it takes is File or URL or String(as the filename/path).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use method : [load(InputStream in)](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/XMLConfiguration.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29)

```
XMLConfiguration config = new XMLConfiguration();
try {
    config.load( context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.kmlsample));

} catch (ConfigurationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```