# Android: How to get a file path from R.raw in res folder?

Tags: android

I have a text file called words.txt in folder raw within android res folder. I don't know how to get its path to make a new file with the given path. I use the code below, but seems it just doesn't work:

```
File file = new File("res/raw/words.txt").getAbsoluteFile();
String filePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
File wordFile = new File(filePath);
```

Comment: what u getting..? error?

Comment: I send this file to a method to extract info from and no content is extracted. This means it ain't read the file. But in java works...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Raw folder url path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966085/raw-folder-url-path)

Answer (score 3):

You can read the `raw/words.txt` as follows:

```
// The InputStream opens the resourceId and sends it to the buffer
InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.words);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String readLine = null;

try {
    // While the BufferedReader readLine is not null 
    while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.d("TEXT", readLine);
}

// Close the InputStream and BufferedReader
is.close();
br.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

*Note: this code must be inside an `Activity` class, as `this.getResources()` refers to `Context.getResources()`*

Comment: Fine, I think you're true. If I copy the file content in a new modifiable file at run-time it would do good. huh?

Comment: Yes that would work. Why do you need the new file anyway? You can just read it using the above method?

Comment: I pass the file as an argument to a method in a different class and the content is extracted there. If the file could actually be sent to that without using a new generated file, it would be better.

Comment: Just one more thing, Do you know where should I put the file, I mean generate it in the sdcard or somewhere? If I want it to be accessible in the internal storage what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You can't write to your own app's res folder. It is not modifiable.

You can create a file here though:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29

If you want to use words.txt as a baseline, you can read from it and copy it to a modifiable file at runtime.

Comment: You mean I use InputStream to copy data from my file and use the generated file?

Comment: Yes, read it like Amulya's answer then write it back to another file (if that's what you want)

Comment: Thanks. I think it's the only way.