# Android WebView LoadUrl Error File Not Found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-webview

I started a blank activity in android studio, Added a Html file to "raw" folder. I created a webview and called function myWebView.loadUrl("file:///res/raw/test.html"). When running the app in the emulator, it shows file not found. Could anyone help?
[image: Phone Emulator][image: Dir in Android Studio]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966085/raw-folder-url-path use it may u get solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this snippet

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.my_webview);
                lWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/htmlfile.html");
```