# Getting file location in android

Tags: java, android, json

I've been stuck on this for a while now.
I'm trying to parse some data from a JSON file. I know the parsing method is working properly (I've created a new java project and tested it separately). But it fails on my android app, and I think it's because I don't include the correct filepath.
This is what I have:

[image]

The method currently returns null in this case, and every reasonable filepath I tried to include.
The courses.json file is the file I intend on including.

Thanks

Edit: Forgot to mention, parseCourses method takes a file path (string) as a parameter

Comment: There is no file system path as that is not a file but a resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try putting it in the following directory

```
res > raw > courses.json
```

to access the file just call

InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.courses);

Comment: Thanks. I moved my file to this location, but thing is I don't need to access the file, my parseCourse method does all that. All I want is to get the file-path to that file. Something like C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Projects\CoursePlanner\app\src\main\res\raw\courses.json (but of course not local to my computer)

Comment: @JasonGreen you can try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966085/raw-folder-url-path

Comment: `I don't need to access the file, my parseCourse method does all that`. In that case YOU need to access the file. Dont confuse us please.

Answer (score 0):

```
parseCourses method takes a file path (string) as a parameter
```

If it cannot read from resources directly then you first have to copy your resource file from resources to somewhere on the file system.