# How to get the URI to a file in raw folder?

Tags: android

The accepted answer to the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966085/raw-folder-url-path) doesn't work anymore.

SDK version : 6
Phone Android Version : 4.4

Comment: do you rely need URI or just access to file (reading)? if you need passing chosen file in your own app it would be better thru resource id instead URI

Comment: I need to share an mp3 file from my app's raw folder with other apps, so I need the Uri.