# How can I get file path on raw resources in Android Studio?

Tags: android, file

I have been using [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/opencv/opencv_face_detection_in_picture.htm) tutorial to make some face detections on picture. The problem is when I getting the file path that used on java

```
String xmlFile = "E:/OpenCV/facedetect/lbpcascade_frontalface.xml";
CascadeClassifier classifier = new CascadeClassifier(xmlFile);
```

How can I translate on android studio. I try put my lbpcascade_frontalface.xml on raw resources. CascadeClassifier is a class that opencv library provided. The only problem is they only loaded string path (on xmlfile). 
this is my code.

```
String pathtoRes = getRawPathAtempt2(context);
CascadeClassifier cascadeClassifier = new CascadeClassifier();
cascadeClassifier.load(pathtoRes);
```

I translated to some method like this.

```
  public String getRawPathAtempt2(Context context) {
    return "android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/raw/" + "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml";
}
```

[image]

I get the asertions error by opencv that tell me the file is null. Thats mean I had been wrong when I used file path on my method. how can I get file path on raw resources? help me please I have been stuck for several days now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> how can i get file path on raw resources?

You can't. There is no path. It is a file on your development machine. It is not a file on the device. Instead, it is an entry in the APK file that is your app on the device.

If your library supports an `InputStream` instead of a filesystem path, `getResources().openRawResource()` on a `Context` to get an `InputStream` on your raw resource.

Comment: thank youu :D, its works. i'm using the inputStream to get where my file and its work :D, i'm sory to bother you again but should i pass the corect code here as an answer or i just keep it to my self the code?

Comment: @Appem: You are certainly welcome to answer your own question, if you like, including details of how you solved the problem. I am glad to hear that you got it working!

Comment: facing same issue, please past the working code for this answer

Comment: What if the library DOES NOT support any stream? I am using a library, and the class has only one constructor that takes a file path as string. What are my options, read the file from raw resource, create a temporary file and write the content to it, and then pass the file's path to the library? Is there any better way than this, like a virtual path or something....

Comment: @DamnVegetables: "What are my options, read the file from raw resource, create a temporary file and write the content to it, and then pass the file's path to the library?" -- that is definitely an option. Or, find a different library. Or, if the library is open source, fork the library and add in stream support.

Answer (score 4):

This is how i solved the problem with @CommonWare Answer

i'm using input stream to get file

```
is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lbpcascade_frontalface);
```

so make the file will be opened and i will make a point to the File class

```
 File cascadeDir = context.getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 mCascadeFile = new File(cascadeDir, "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");
```

and then i make a search to the path file using getAbsolutePath like this

```
 cascadeClassifier.load(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

take a look at my full code

```
try {
        is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lbpcascade_frontalface);
        File cascadeDir = context.getDir("cascade", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        mCascadeFile = new File(cascadeDir, "lbpcascade_frontalface.xml");

        os = new FileOutputStream(mCascadeFile);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }

        is.close();
        os.close();

        cascadeClassifier.load(mCascadeFile.getAbsolutePath());


    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.i(TAG, "face cascade not found");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Uri video = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.test.test/raw/filename");
```

Using this you can access the file in raw folder, if you want to access the file in asset folder use this URL...

```
file:///android_asset/filename
```

Make sure you don't add the extension to the filename. E.g. "/movie" not "/movie.mp4".

Refer to this link:

[Raw folder url path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966085/raw-folder-url-path)

Answer (score 0):

We can use this Alternative method for finding the path of Files in Raw Folder.

```
InputStream inputStreamdat=getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.face_landmark_model);
File model=getDir("model", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
File modelFile=new 
File(model,"face_landmark_model.dat");        
FileOutputStream os1 = new 
FileOutputStream(modelFile);
byte[] buffer1 = new byte[4096];
int bytesRead1;
        while ((bytesRead1=inputStreamdat.read(buffer1))!=-1) {
            os1.write(buffer1, 0, bytesRead1);
        }
        inputStreamdat.close();
        os1.close();
```

You Can Use
modelFile.getAbsolutePath()); For getting the Path