# Finding the path of a file in the raw folder?

Tags: java, android, path

I try to have the path in string of some fbx and shp file in my project's raw folder in android studio.
I have try a lots of think but it never work.

```
String file= getExternalFilesDir(null).getAbsolutePath() + "/tree.fbx";
//or
Uri uri = Uri.parse(
                "android.resource://"
                        + getPackageName()
                        + "/"
                        + R.raw.tree
        );
        String uritree=uri.getPath();
//or
String modelURI = new File(this.getDataDir().getAbsolutePath()+"/raw", "tree.fbx").getAbsolutePath();
```

I don't want to open the file, I realy need to have the path to be using in another library.

Comment: Things in the raw folder are resources.  They aren't files.  They cannot be accessed as files.  If you need to access it as a file, write it to your filesystem first

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Raw folder url path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7966085/raw-folder-url-path)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're close. Try a slight variation of your 2nd option, instead of using R.raw.tree in your path, use raw/tree:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/tree");
```