# How to get Uri of res folder?

Tags: android

I am trying to get the Uri of an image I have in the drawable folder. I tried many possible ways but nothing seems to work. Can anyone suggest me how to get the Uri of res folder. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Well, it's actually quite easy. a base URI for a resource in your package would be something like the following possibilities:

```
android.resource://[package]/[resource_id]
android.resource://[package]/[res type]/[res name]
```

So the following would be managable.

```
String pkgName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+pkgName+"/" + R.drawable.icon);
Uri otherPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+pkgName+"/drawable/icon");
```

You can find more about this at http://androidbook.blogspot.com/2009/08/referring-to-android-resources-using.html

Comment: btw, you can get the packahe name like this: getContext().getPackageName()