# What is the include file of getURLForResource()?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm creating an app that want to get some URL at the time of execution on the app layout folder. How can I get the URL on the application run to the program?

Comment: do you want the URL? or just the resource?

Comment: i want the url for the layout file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would generally not recommend to do anything inside the layout folder, since this doesn't handle screen sizes, android versions etc. But here you go:

```
Uri otherPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://my.package.name/layout/[your resource]");
Log.d(TAG, otherPath.toString());
```

change `my.package.name` to your package name and `[your resource]` with your resource name

src: [How to get Uri of res folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977348/how-to-get-uri-of-res-folder)

Comment: i want to change the url into string can you help me with that\