# Android get image path from drawable as string

Tags: android, drawable

Is there any way that I can get the image path from drawable folder in android as String. I need this because I implement my own viewflow where I'm showing the images by using their path on sd card, but I want to show a default image when there is no image to show.

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: As I read [here][1] it isn't possible because the files are inside the apk.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301493/android-get-path-of-resource

Comment: This is the correct answer . http://stackoverflow.com/a/25758286/7795876

Comment: Hi, how do you show image from path ???

Answer (score 55):

These all are ways:

```
String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.image;
```

Other ways I tested

```
Uri path = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.segf4ult.test/" + R.drawable.icon);
Uri otherPath = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.segf4ult.test/drawable/icon");

String path = path.toString();
String path = otherPath .toString();
```

Comment: I am getting file format not supported error with all of them.

Comment: such pattern returns FileNotFound Exception

Answer (score 27):

based on the some of above replies i improvised it a bit

create this method and call it by passing your resource

**Reusable Method**

```
public String getURLForResource (int resourceId) {
    //use BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID instead of R.class.getPackage().getName() if both are not same
    return Uri.parse("android.resource://"+R.class.getPackage().getName()+"/" +resourceId).toString();
}
```

**Sample call**

```
getURLForResource(R.drawable.personIcon)
```

complete **example of loading image**

```
String imageUrl = getURLForResource(R.drawable.personIcon);
// Load image
 Glide.with(patientProfileImageView.getContext())
          .load(imageUrl)
          .into(patientProfileImageView);
```

you can move the function getURLForResource to a Util file and make it *static* so it can be reused

Comment: The only answer that works for me. How compatible is this composed URL across Android flavors from different providers?

Comment: @AshishJain, you need to share more information, like the Android version; whats the  image type, where the is image placed error if any, etc..

Comment: I am trying same code for Android all version like 8,9 and 10 and passing vector image (.xml) but it doesn't showing on my custom recyclerview.

Comment: @AshishJain the above code has been tested for compatibility with regular images only not SVG

Comment: you should use BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID instead of R.class.getPackage().getName() cause some people name the package different than the app id

Answer (score 3):

If you are planning to get the image from its path, it's better to use Assets instead of trying to figure out the path of the drawable folder.

```
    InputStream stream = getAssets().open("image.png");
    Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(stream, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you cannot get it as `String` but you can get it as `int` by get resource `id`:

```
int resId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("imageNameHere", "drawable", this.getPackageName());
```

Answer (score -6):

First check whether the file exists in SDCard. If the file doesnot exists in SDcard then you can set image using setImageResource() methodand passing default image from drawable folder

Sample Code

```
File imageFile = new File(absolutepathOfImage);//absolutepathOfImage is absolute path of image including its name
        if(!imageFile.exists()){//file doesnot exist in SDCard

        imageview.setImageResource(R.drawable.defaultImage);//set default image from drawable folder
        }
```