# Print logo on top of recipe android

Tags: android, string, path, android-drawable

Hello guys i have the problem that i want to include an image in my project and when the user click the print button the image will be printet followed by other information but i dont get it to pass the image path to the PrintTool

```
PrintTool.printPhotoWithPath(imagePath, this);
```

and the first line in printtool are this

```
public static void printPhotoWithPath(String filePath, Context context) {

    // Get the picture based on the path
    File mfile = new File(filePath/*path*/);
    if (mfile.exists()) {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath/*path*/);
        byte[] command = decodeBitmap(bmp);
        printPhoto(command, context);


    }else{
        Log.e("PrintTools_58mm", "the file isn't exists");
    }
}
```

So my problem is, how can i get the path from my image in drawable folder to the code?

Answer (score 0):

Please remove this line

```
File mfile = new File(filePath/*path*/);
```

Provided the image is currently in your drawable directory, you can get it like this:

```
if (mfile.exists()) {
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getResources(), R.drawable.<yourDrawableName>);
    byte[] command = decodeBitmap(bmp);
    printPhoto(command, context);
}else{
    Log.e("PrintTools_58mm", "the file isn't exists");
}
```

**NB** Replace  with the name of your Drawable.

If you require the path of the Bitmap, by default it is

```
String imageUri = "drawable://" + R.drawable.image;
```

[Refer to this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601070/android-get-image-path-from-drawable-as-string)

Comment: so i have tried your method but now it says Cannot Resolve method getResources()

Comment: Sorry you need context. Try 'getContext().getResources()', depending on whether it's a Fragment or Activity, you can also try 'getApplicationContext().getResources()'

Comment: Its nothing of the above mentioned this is in an Activity PrintTool.printPhotoWithPath(imagePath, this); the other stuff is just PrintTool.java its just a class

Answer (score 0):

i hope this helps you

```
File file  = new File(String.valueOf(R.mipmap.imgeName));
        file.getPath();
```