# Get path of a drawable image so that I can post it to the backend

Tags: android, file, android-studio, android-drawable, android-resources

I have a set of icons stored in the drawable folder.

Based on users selection I'll be posting these icons to the backend.

When I try to retrieve the path for these drawables, I get the following error

HTTP FAILED: java.io.FileNotFoundException: (No such file or directory)

This is how I am getting the path

```
public String getURLForResource (int resourceId) {
        return Uri.parse("android.resource://"+ BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+"/" +resourceId).toString();
    }

File fileToUpload  = new File(getURLForResource(R.drawable.icon));
```

I have referred the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301493/get-path-of-android-resource) says that it's not possible to retrieve the path for a drawable.

Any idea on how I can solve this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601070/android-get-image-path-from-drawable-as-string

Comment: yes, it's not possible, because it is not in a physical file system

Answer (score 1):

As solution you can write your drawable to file.

#### Convert drawable to bitmap

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), R.drawable.your_drawable);
```

#### Save bitmap to file

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File file = new File(path, "image" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
    out.flush(); // Not really required
    out.close(); // do not forget to close the stream
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can use file now.