# Accessing a resource file in Android

Tags: android

I've been fiddling around with this for quite some time. I can't work out why my file /res/raw/video.mp4 can't be found by my Android app. I am on API 15 and the phone is up to date with v4.0.3.

The test code currently looks like this:

```
String file = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.movie; 
File f = new File(file);
message = f.exists() ? "file exists" : "file missing";
```

All combinations I have tried so far results in the message string being returned as "file missing". What is the correct way to access a file from the resources? Tried the obvious ones "/res/raw/video.mp4" etc too but all failed.

Comment: This answer might come helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2856501/1063730

Comment: Yes, it seems I am able to open it up in an inputstream using that one but I need to get the address as a string in order to use ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail() which is my main goal (but i'd like to get to the bottom of why my example is not working regardless).

Comment: Well, that'll teach me to read the comments before posting an answer... yoshi posted a link saying the same thing as my answer.  :p

Comment: It's not working becasue there is no directoy structure in a compiled apk.  It's just data.  The framework knows where/how to look for different things in there (`getResources()`, etc) , but it's not a directory structure as we think of it at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to open a stream to process the file you should be doing this:

```
InputStream raw = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.movie);
```

**EDIT**

Ok, now that I know exactly what you want, I have bad news.  Not really possible.

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301493/android-get-path-of-resource)

Basically you would need to copy the file out of resources to somewhere that you can get at it like the SD card or internal storage.

Comment: Yes, that works but I don't need to open up an InputStream for this test.

Answer (score 0):

`String url = "file:///android_asset/raw/filename.jpg`";

Comment: Same result. Tried "new File("file:///android_asset/raw/video.mp4")". Also tried "file:///android_asset/res/raw/video.mp4" but that too didn't work.