# Get a list of filenames in a drawable resource directory

Tags: android, android-resources, android-drawable

I want to get a list of certain filenames in a drawable resource directory (at runtime, not using XML). I guess, I would need to distinguish certain files from others. So ...
**res/drawable-hdpi/mysubdir

    --   x-one.png

    --   one.png

    --   x-two.png

    --   two.png

    --   x-three.png

    --   three.png
**
I want to put the `x-*.png` filenames into a `List<String>`. Is this possible?
Borrowing some code from another question, I can get *all* the drawables, but I don't see a way to distinguish one from another in a meaningful way.

```
private void getDrawableResources() {

final R.drawable drawableResources = new R.drawable();
final Class<R.drawable> drawableClass = R.drawable.class;
final Field[] fields = drawableClass.getDeclaredFields();
final List<Integer> resourceIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0, max = fields.length; i < max; i++) {
    final int resourceId;
    try {
        resourceId = fields[i].getInt(drawableResources);
        resourceIdList.add(resourceId);
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {
        continue;
    }
}

Resources resources = this.getActivity().getResources();
for (int i = 0; i < resourceIdList.size(); i++) {
        Drawable drawable = resources.getDrawable(resourceIdList.get(i));
        resourceIdList.get(i) + "): " +  drawable.toString());
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Resource directories do not support subdirectories.

Comment: That question was in the back of my mind. I was ignoring it. I will edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use FileNameFilter while getting list of files in a directory.

```
      File dir = new File(dirLocation);

      if(dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory())
        {
            File[] files = dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter()
            {
                public boolean accept(File dir, String name)
                {
                    return name.contains("X-");
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: According to this question, this is not possible:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301493/android-get-path-of-resource