# Not able to get path of the image in Resources/drawable in xamarin project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to send an email from my app with an image embedded in it. For this I am trying to get the path of image in the Resources/drawable in my app.

Following is the code to attach an image to mail through Linkedresource :

```
            AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(Body.ToString(), null, "text/html");

            LinkedResource LR_body = new LinkedResource("Here comes path of the image in Resources/drawable");

            LR_body.ContentId = "image.png";

            htmlView.LinkedResources.Add(LR_body );
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);
```

I am not able to get the path of image in the Resources/drawable in my app. Please help me in resolving the issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19574454/4984832

Comment: Getting the same exception while adding the path to Linkedresource.

Comment: You will have to get the resource as a stream, save to a temp file and the pass that new path to LinkedResource.