# why my MP4 video is not playing in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

My android studio  is activity is not building  i dont know waht is the  meant by Resolve 1900002 value.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Assets not Resources. Resource ID's are exactly that, just ID's. If you really want to store the mp4 as a resource, then look at this other question: [Get path of Android resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301493/get-path-of-android-resource)

Comment: hbtw asset folder doesnt supports  Mp4 files ?