# How can I get the file path with Kotlin when the files locate in the drawbale folder in Android Studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, openai-api

The Code A comes from the [project](https://github.com/aallam/openai-kotlin.git).
The author get the file path with  `val resourcesPrefix = "src/nativeMain/resources"` and `FileSource(path = "$resourcesPrefix/image.png".toPath() ...`,   you can see the file structure with Image A.

The Image B is the file structure of my project, how can I get the file path? so I can pass the path parameter to the function `ImageEdit(...)` .

BTW, I don't know whether the Code C is correct.

**Code A**

```
val resourcesPrefix = "src/nativeMain/resources"

println("\n> Edit images...")
val imageEdit = ImageEdit(
    image = FileSource(path = "$resourcesPrefix/image.png".toPath(), fileSystem = FileSystem.SYSTEM),
    mask = FileSource(path = "$resourcesPrefix/mask.png".toPath(), fileSystem = FileSystem.SYSTEM),
    prompt = "a sunlit indoor lounge area with a pool containing a flamingo",
    n = 1,
    size = ImageSize.is1024x1024,
)
```

**Image A**
[image]

**Code B**

```
val resourcesPrefix = "?????"
val imageEdit = ImageEdit(
      image = FileSource(path = "$resourcesPrefix/image.png".toPath(), fileSystem = FileSystem.SYSTEM),
        mask = FileSource(path = "$resourcesPrefix/mask.png".toPath(), fileSystem = FileSystem.SYSTEM),
        prompt = "a sunlit indoor lounge area with a pool containing a flamingo",
        n = 1,
        size = ImageSize.is256x256,
)
```

**Image B**
[image]

**Code C**

```
        val file1="drawable://" + R.drawable.image
        val file2="drawable://" + R.drawable.mask
        val imageEdit = ImageEdit(
            image = FileSource(path = file1.toPath(), fileSystem = FileSystem.SYSTEM),
            mask = FileSource(path = file1.toPath(), fileSystem = FileSystem.SYSTEM),
            prompt = "a sunlit indoor lounge area with a pool containing a flamingo",
            n = 1,
            size = ImageSize.is256x256,
        )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get path of Android resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301493/get-path-of-android-resource)

Comment: There is no file path, as those are files on your development machine, not on the Android device.

Answer (score 0):

To get a `Source` for drawable, sound, and raw resources, you can use this function:

```kotlin
fun Context.getResourceSource(resource: Int): Source {
    return resources.openRawResource(resource).source()
}
```

Use the function to create a `FileSource`:

```kotlin
val source = getResourceSource(R.drawable.mask)
val fileSource = FileSource("mask.png", source)
```